# Revs too low after changing gear

Tags: forza-horizon-3

I have a car which is underperforming when changing up gears.

Changing from first to second is fine, but changing up every other gear results in the car feeling like it is revving too low.

The powerband of the car is about 6500rpm and even if I change on the limiter, the engine is still below the powerband after the gear change, making it feel sluggish and slow.

How can I improve this? How can I ensure that the car is in the powerband after changing gear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your gear ratios are too long. Because you are covering so much change in speed per gear, when you change into the next gear up it's got a lot of distance to cover before it's ready to change up again, so it'll be coming in at low RPMs then leaving at a higher RPM.

The best way to counteract this is by shortening your gear ratios. The less time you spend in each gear the faster the acceleration, but be aware that this can impact your top speed, or you can end up with a massively long final gear.